# Where crontab -e saves data?

Tags: cron

Where cron file for user and for root is saved after executing

```
crontab -e
```

and saving data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/var/spool/cron/username
Use `su` to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Each user can have their own crontab, and these files are in /var.